# How to convert JSON Data to Avro format using Python

Tags: python, json, avro, fastavro

I would like to convert the below JSON data to avro format, I used the below code snippet to write the JSON data in avro format but received an error. If anyone can help with this, it would be really great.

```
from fastavro import writer, reader, schema
from rec_avro import to_rec_avro_destructive, from_rec_avro_destructive, rec_avro_schema

def getweatherdata():
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.441792&lon=-94.037689&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=' + apikey
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    return data
 
def turntoavro():
    avro_objects = (to_rec_avro_destructive(rec) for rec in getweatherdata())
    with open('json_in_avro.avro', 'wb') as f_out:
        writer(f_out, schema.parse_schema(rec_avro_schema()), avro_objects)



turntoavro()
```

```
    Error details:
    
      File "fastavro/_write.pyx", line 269, in fastavro._write.write_record
    TypeError: Expected dict, got str
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "datalake.py", line 30, in <module>
        turntoavro()
      File "datalake.py", line 26, in turntoavro
        writer(f_out, schema.parse_schema(rec_avro_schema()), avro_objects)
      File "fastavro/_write.pyx", line 652, in fastavro._write.writer
      File "fastavro/_write.pyx", line 605, in fastavro._write.Writer.write
      File "fastavro/_write.pyx", line 341, in fastavro._write.write_data
      File "fastavro/_write.pyx", line 278, in fastavro._write.write_record
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Sample Data:

```
    {
      "lat": 33.44,
      "lon": -94.04,
      "timezone": "America/Chicago",
      "timezone_offset": -18000

   }
```

Comment: Can you post a full example? I'm not sure what `to_red_avro_destructive()` does. It looks like the problem is that you are passing in strings instead of dictionaries as your records.

Comment: I have added the necessary information , can you please check now.

Comment: The example you have still can't be run. You call a `to_rec_avro_destructive` function but you don't show what that does.

Comment: to_rec_avro_destructive() function is imported from rec_avro library

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the response to the request you made, you used `response.text` which returns the response as a string and not in JSON format. You have to use `response.json()` instead to have it in JSON format:

```
import json    
def getweatherdata():
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.441792&lon=-94.037689&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=' + apikey
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data
     
def turntoavro():
    avro_objects = (to_rec_avro_destructive(rec) for rec in getweatherdata())
    with open('json_in_avro.avro', 'wb') as f_out:
        writer(f_out, schema.parse_schema(rec_avro_schema()), avro_objects)
    
    
    
turntoavro()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the answers, you probably want to use `response.json()` rather than `response.text` so that you get back an actual JSON dictionary.

However, the other problem is that `getweatherdata()` returns a single dictionary so when you do `avro_objects = (to_rec_avro_destructive(rec) for rec in getweatherdata())` you are iterating over the keys in that dictionary. Instead you should do `avro_objects = [to_rec_avro_destructive(getweatherdata())]`

I believe this code should work for you:

```
from fastavro import writer, reader, schema
from rec_avro import to_rec_avro_destructive, from_rec_avro_destructive, rec_avro_schema

def getweatherdata():
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.441792&lon=-94.037689&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=' + apikey
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data
 
def turntoavro():
    avro_objects = [to_rec_avro_destructive(getweatherdata())]
    with open('json_in_avro.avro', 'wb') as f_out:
        writer(f_out, schema.parse_schema(rec_avro_schema()), avro_objects)

turntoavro()
```